# Running multiple application with single codeigniter base folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-3

I found the official document quite confusing for folder structure about creating multiple application on single base folder of CI (CodeIgniter).

Here: [Managing your Applications](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html)

Let say i have a base folder `/ci` under web root directory `/www` so my project folder structure is

> /www/ci

Now according to the mentioned tutorial in above link, if i create `myapp1` sub-folder under `/application` folder of `ci` will be

> /ci/application/myapp1
>
> **main index.php path**: /ci/index.php

myapp1/ folder structure: (below)

*In official tutorial link, they have mentioned `/applications` instead `/application` to confuse us more*

> /config
>
> /controllers
>
> /libraries
>
> /models
>
> /views

Now if i update `$application_folder` the main index.php file `/ci/index.php` to point to this application folder will be

```
$application_folder = 'application/myapp1';
```

I can access it using route

> http://localhost/ci/

**Question:1**
But it will no longer be able to use the main application folder /ci/application or if i create new application myapp2 sub-folder inside application folder, then how to access it?

**Question:2**
According to documentation:

> Each of your applications will need its own index.php file which calls
>   the desired application. The index.php file can be named anything you
>   want.

But the million$ question is **where to put those own `index.php` files?**

> **Note:** I am not asking about the **2nd method** of having separate new application folders parallel with main application folder. I have already successfully implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Use following structure:
`/www/ci1` directory for 1st site
`/www/ci2` directory for 2nd site

Both `ci1` and `ci2` will be same structure and will contain index.php file.
under `ci1` and `ci2` structure will be as follow:

```
/config
/controllers
/libraries
/models
/views
index.php
```

and `system` the directory is `/www/system`.

Now change:

`$system_path = 'system'` to `$system_path = '../system'` in both `index.php`

And you are done. You can access both site `ci1` and `ci2`. if you want `ci3`,`ci4`, `...` `cin` you can just create a new folder and change in `index.php`

Comment: @airful-shirshir Thanks for you reply. but i had added a Note in end that using this 2nd method i have already tried successfully. My question is regarding the documented method.

Comment: "The index.php file can be named anything you want", so those will be in same directory with different name. eg. site1.php, site2.php